# Importing Bootstrap from CDN, not animating

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Appraisal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=VT323" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="animated bounceInUp">dummy text</h1>
      <hr>
      <h4>portfolio</h4>
    </header>

    <div class="slides">

    </div>

    <div class="skills">


    </div>

    <div class="certs">


    </div>

    <footer>


    </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to import Bootstrap from the cdn links provided on the site. I believe I have done everything correctly, however the animations tied to the h1 tag in the header will not animate. Can anyone see anything that is wrong?

Comment: Double check how to use the class, where is it linked in the scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation you're tying to achieve is with MDBootstrap (Material Design for Bootstrap), and it isn't included with the base Bootstrap files. To use the animation methods you want, include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.3.2/css/mdb.min.css">
```

after your Bootstrap CSS files, and include

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.3.2/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

after your current scripts at the end of the body content. That should be all you need to achieve the animations!

### Dynamically generate animations using jQuery

You can also dynamically generate your animations by using the `addClass` jQuery method:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("h1").addClass("animated bounceInUp"); });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import the CDN for `Animate.css`. Add this into your `<head>`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
```

Your browser is literally seeing `animated bounceInUp` as 
`Huh? What is this "animated" and "bounceInUp"? Oi! Developerrrr!? Hello! What are these?` - Your browser.

Comment: I guess that humor isn't allowed here, but I did answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in `script` tag

```
wow = new WOW({
    boxClass: 'wow', // default
    animateClass: 'animated', // default
    offset: 0, // default
    mobile: true, // default
    live: true // default
})
wow.init();
```

and add this `class="wow"` in your html component